# How does C work when int is converted to float?

Tags: c

If we have a 32bit pattern of 1111 1111 1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000, which is -2^23 in int, when we convert int to float will this be -INF?

Comment: *How* are you converting it?  Do you mean just float f = i; ?

Comment: To what level as well?  For instance, on ARM, it will take that value from the integer register and move it to a floating point register, then it will recognize it as a float for further work.

Comment: yes that is what I mean.

Comment: Might help to have a quick driver program as example to show exactly where you are confused as well.

Comment: oh really? I did not know that.  Umm I want to know what goes on in the compiler how the C compiler interprets it.

Comment: oh okay I'll try running it now

Comment: hmm.. my guess was wrong... It prints it well

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/WMLNJ5 shows exactly what the compiler does (ARM) - you can select x86 or whatever from here as well.

Comment: IEEE 754 encoding of floating point numbers state that exponent 255 and fraction 0 is represented as -INF(if the sign bit is 1) in single precision(float), then I thought int is also a 4byte data type so what is the value of -INF is in int... sorry for the lame question guys

Comment: No problem - thank you for working through the problem with us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conversions in C operate on *values*, and the value -2^23 is representable in `float`, so the result of the conversion is the value -2^23.